# Web Mapping Laptop, Mac vs PC

Tags: qgis, geoserver, mac

I've been doing GIS for about a decade now and was under the impression to avoid using Macs if using ArcMap because it runs on Windows OS. I've heard that if one really wished to run ArcMap on a Mac it's possible to have parallel OSs or use a virtual box and that this type of technology is pretty solid these days.

I need to replace my PC laptop and have been getting more and more interested using open source alternatives like QGIS and GeoServer to make web mapping services. Additionally, I would be using the laptop to log into a remote virtual machine I use for work that has ArcMap on it so the OS on the laptop wouldn't matter for that purpose.

I occasionally attend an open hack night for web mappers and I'm usually the only one there with a PC laptop. Is there any reason why I should switch to a Mac or should I just stick with a PC?

Comment: There's a number of variables unmentioned here, including the web browser, and most of them are more religious than technical, which makes it difficult to clear the *opinion-based* hurdle here in GIS SE.  See also the [Don't Ask](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page for hints on how to avoid a subjective question.

Comment: Not unless you want to spend too much money on a machine with outdated hardware. Apple is mainly a phone manufacturer now, they are less interested in their computers than ever and it shows. http://www.theverge.com/2016/8/4/12373776/2012-macbook-pro-still-alive-not-dead-why

Comment: I suppose it is a question looking for a subjective response. My apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say get a Dell Laptop and go Linux, and prepare to set up virtual machines to test server deployments and operating system behavior. (you can find Dell machines on their website that ship with Ubuntu not windows, so you save a few hundred $$$)

So depending on your server, here's what I would recommend

**Ubuntu Server**
- Linux Mint Desktop
- Ubuntu Server Virtual Machine
-- Both will give you experience deploying in 'apt' repository environment

**CentOS**
- Fedora Desktop
- CentOS Virtual Machine
-- Both will give you experience deploying in 'yum' repository environment